# How to remove hidden line breaks in character content?

Tags: r, stringr, stringi

I have a text like this:

```
"Hello how
are you" %>% word(-1)
```

I get an error if I perform this because I pressed Enter after `how`. How do I remove the hidden line break so as to perform my code on the text?

Comment: Not reproducible.  `> library(tidyverse)
> "Hello how
+ are you" %>% word(-1)
[1] "you"
> `

Comment: Do exactly what I wrote: write

"Hello how"

then press Enter

then write

"are you"

Comment: Same here, with R 4.2.1 and stringr 1.4.1 & stringi 1.7.8 it runs through just fine (Win10, RStudio 2022.07.01) .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the exact mechanism to make this reproducible.
This happens under 2 conditions that are my default way to process code in R.

- In a chunk
- You don't execute the chunk, but the line pressing ENTER + CTRL

Solution: execute the chunk instead.

Comment: The fact you were working in Markdown would have been a *very useful* piece of information in your original post.  You know what your "default way to process code" is.  We don't.